# Creating EMR machine from an EC2 machine with boto (with IAM role) gets failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

When I try to create an EMR machine with boto from an already created EC2 machine with role (having almost all authorities) it gets failed with error "Access denied checking jar: s3n://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar".

My question is what are the general steps to follow to run a boto script with IAM role from an EC2 machine so that it can create an EMR machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer from original poster @user1010900 :

Got the answer for now:

"EMR currently cannot use an IAM role assigned to the EC2 instance launching the EMR job."

Ref:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=531826&#531826

AWS EMR does not support AWS STS now.

Ref:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/UsingTokens.html

Thanks